# Load Child Block in Loop

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I am working to print multiple order once. I have used the following code to get order email html section.

```
foreach($orderIds as $orderId):

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    Mage::unregister('current_order');
    Mage::register('current_order', $order);

    echo $this->getChildHtml('sales.order.print');
endforeach;
```

But If I have multiple orders it repeats every time. but showing the same order. Every time same Child HTML loading, not changing dynamically. My question is how to load child block dynamically with changed value every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the same order for all the cases because the children html is 'cached' in a member variable. See how the `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::_getChildHtml()` method looks like (that one is called by `getChildHtml`).
To get the new html each time you need to transform this line:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('sales.order.print');
```

into this one:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('sales.order.print', false);
```

The second parameter means the content is not cached, and it's recreated each time.

Comment: @Great Marius .. Thanks a lot .. saved my day

Comment: Also saved my day, cheers